# eclipse dynamic web project default start page

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I created an eclipse dynamic web project, with home.jsp in the WEB-INF folder

The server I'm using is Tomcat 7.0.35

The name of the project is Pilot_1, and I have a servlet which triggers when the URL-pattern is /home

```
@WebServlet(description = "Initalizes the table", urlPatterns = { "/home" })
```

I want to specify the URL so that everytime I press Project > Run > Run on Server, the URL is specifically localhost:8080/Pilot_1/home (triggering both the servlet and the jsp page).

I tried changing the Context Root to only "Pilot_1", which gives the URL "localhost:8080/Pilot_1" and doesn't trigger the servlet

I tried changing the Context Root to "Pilot_1/home", which gives the URL "localhost:8080/Pilot/1/home/" and the extra '/' ensures that the servlet doesn't trigger

I tried changing the Context Root to to "home", which gives the URL "localhost:8080/home/", and again, the extra '/' ensures that the servlet doesn't trigger

I've been playing around with URLs and it seems the only time the servlet gets triggered is when the URL is "localhost:8080/Pilot_1/home"

Is there any workaround to this?

This is my web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't mess with the Context root. Instead, go to the `web.xml` file and change the `welcome-file-list`:

```html
<welcome-file-list>
    <!-- note that THIS IS NOT home.jsp, just home (the URL mapping of your servlet) -->
    <welcome-file>home</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

By the way, revert any change you have done to the context root of the application.

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15150652/1065197) for an example.

Comment: I just added the edit to include my web.xml mapping for welcome-file.

Comment: I reverted back the context root to default (Pilot_1) and adjusted my web.xml as per Luiggi's comment, but now the URL is "localhost:8080/Pilot_1" on run, and nothing shows up. It seems that the page home.jsp doesn't even get read anymore.

Comment: You should have `http://localhost:8080/Pilot_1/`, clean and build your project and redeploy it again. Also, make sure you done a forward in your Servlet `doGet` method.

Comment: I do have that. But now the webpage is blank. Neither home.jsp nor the servlet gets triggered.

Comment: @user2076874 please check the link in my answer, it's not for decoration purpose =\ , there I show that I forward to the desired page in the `doGet` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really wish I had this explanation when I started working with Java web development. Thanks again!

Comment: @user2076874 you're welcome (I also wanted to have that explanation like 4 years ago)